# "apps & features" missing programs that are in program files on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

While moving apps from my C drive to my D drive to free ups space, I noticed the majority of apps and .exe files I've downloaded outside the Microsoft and installed in program files folder aren't being recognized by my computer. They don't show up in Start or "Apps and Features" or any of the other Windows features that are supposed to recognize your installed apps like "open with" options. I've already tried running the SFC/System File Checker and rebuilding the Index in the control panel indexing options, as well as updating and restarting the computer.

I'm wondering if there's a proper way to install apps off the internet so that the system recognizes them in the program files folder, and if there are other methods of scanning my program files folder to have these apps get recognized by Windows.

Comment: Please provide some screenshots.  IncludingAdd/Remove Programs as an edit to your question

Comment: Did these missing apps *ever* show up in Start or in Apps and Features?